# Array with objects, check for unique member

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have an array of objects all have a public member called id, I would like to remove all "duplicates":

This is my attempt:

```
<?php


$a = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;

$b = new stdClass;
$b->id = 2;

$c = new stdClass;
$c->id = 3;

$d = new stdClass;
$d->id = 1;

$objects = array($a, $b, $c, $d);

var_dump( (array) $objects);

echo '<hr>';

$temp = $objects;

foreach ($objects as &$object) {

    foreach ($temp as $object2) {
        if ($object2->id === $object->id) {
            unset($object);
            continue;
        }
    }

}

echo '<hr>';

var_dump($objects);

?>

Notice: Undefined variable: object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\objects.php on line 25

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\objects.php on line 25
```

What am I missing here? Is there any in-built function to accomplish this instead maybe?

Comment: use `array_unique()`;

Comment: cannot convert that to a string you know

Comment: You must add a paremeter in your continue to jump two loops. Exemple continue 2;

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach with only a loop and with a temporary array that will keep ids

```
<?php

$a = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;

$b = new stdClass;
$b->id = 2;

$c = new stdClass;
$c->id = 3;

$d = new stdClass;
$d->id = 1;

$objects = array($a, $b, $c, $d);

var_dump( (array) $objects);

echo '<hr>';

$temp = $array;
$ids = array();

foreach ($objects as  $object) {
    if (!in_array($object->id, $ids)) {
        $temp[] = $object;
        $ids[] = $object->id;
    }
}


echo '<hr>';

var_dump($objects);
var_dump($temp);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be found in [documentation comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#76769).
Once adapted to your need it will be like :

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;

$b = new stdClass;
$b->id = 2;

$c = new stdClass;
$c->id = 3;

$d = new stdClass;
$d->id = 1;

$objects = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
$idlist= array();
$callback = function($col)use(&$idlist){
    if(!isset($col->id)){
       $idlist[$col->id] = true;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
$unique = array_filter( $array, $callback );
var_dump( $array );
var_dump( $unique );
```

As far as your current code is concerned your error comes from the "unset" directive.
You have two loops and in the deepest one you destroy the variable created by the first loop. If this destruction happens at iteration 1, when you want to test at iteration 2, php says the variable does not exist as it actually no longer exists.